# Calculating complex line integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to calculate
$\int_{\gamma} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2}$ for $\gamma(t)=e^{it},t \in [0,2 \pi]$ using the definition of the line integral.

Using the definition of the line integral I get

$\int_{\gamma} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2}=\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{i(e^{it})}}{(e^{it})^2} ie^{it}dt=\int_0^{2 \pi} i\frac{e^{i(e^{it})}}{e^{it}}  dt$

Now I am stuck at $\int_0^{2 \pi} i\frac{e^{i(e^{it})}}{e^{it}}dt$. Does anybody know how to continue from here on?

Comment: Your notation is a bit confusion. Is $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$ and $t\in[0,2\pi]$?

Comment: @spinosarus123 Sorry, that was a typo, I did edit it

Comment: Are you not allowed to use the residue formula ?

Comment: @Abezhiko No, I am trying to use only the definition of the line integral

Comment: The antiderivative is not elementary. According to Maple, $$i\int \!{{\rm e}^{i \left( {{\rm e}^{it}}-t \right) }}\,{\rm d}t=-{
{\rm e}^{i \left( {{\rm e}^{it}}-t \right) }}-i{\rm Ei}_1 \left(-i{
{\rm e}^{it}} \right) $$  with definite integral $-2\pi$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Did you recently learn about residues, by chance...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang No, recently I have been learning about Integration and power series

Comment: I see; in that case, did you recently learn about termwise integration? If so, expanding the numerator $e^{iz}$ as a power series about $0$ and integrating termwise works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go is a power expansion of the exponential, as suggested by Andrew D. Hwang in the comment section, which is equivalent to rederiving Cauchy's residue theorem actually. We have :
$$
\oint_C \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2} \,\mathrm{d}z = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{i^k}{k!} \oint_C z^{k-2} \,\mathrm{d}z,
$$
where $C$ is the unit circle. Parametrizing the said unit circle as you did leads to
$$
\oint_C z^n \,\mathrm{d}z = i\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(n+1)t} \,\mathrm{d}t = 
\begin{cases}
   2\pi i & \mathrm{if}\; n = -1 \\
   0      & \mathrm{otherwise} 
\end{cases},
$$
hence finally $\oint_C \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2} \,\mathrm{d}z = -2\pi$.